# How to send an email without a framework with Javascript

Tags: javascript, email

I need help with my project, please help How to send an email without a framework with Javascript

Comment: What have you tried already? You need to show people what you have done and explain where you are getting stuck.

Comment: My English is weak. I can't give you much information

Comment: I've made the entry system for now. I'm asking about the recording system. Entry system codes:

Comment: I can't write too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send email with javascript by doing an API call.
Follow this article: https://medium.com/@mariusc23/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-b53319616782